# Find all ideals of ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ containing 4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> How to find all ideals of ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ containing $4$?

Since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(4) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[X]/(X^2+3)$, I tried to find all ideals of $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[X]/(X^2+3)$. But I was stuck because $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field. Is there any good way?

Comment: Consider all the ways to factor $4$ in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$

Comment: Notice that $X^2+3\equiv X^2-1 = (X-1)(X+1)\mod 4$ and hence $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)[X]/(X^2+3) \cong \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @user218931 Since $<(X-1)> + <(X+1)> \neq (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[X]$ I think we can't use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Whoops, sorry then!

Comment: @JasonM  Since $4=(1+\sqrt{-3})(1-\sqrt{-3})=(2)(2)$,I expect that all the ideals containing 4 is generated by some of them.But I can't justify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)[X]/(X^2+3) = (\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)[X]/(X^2-1)$ is a ring with only 16 elements, one may find all the ideals by hand. It is a local ring with maximal ideal $(X+1,X-1)$. Sitting directly below are $(X+1)$, $(X-1)$, and $(2X)$. $(2X+2)$ is contained in all of them, and $(2)$ is only contained in $(2X)$. Together with the trivial ideals, this gives 8 ideals.

The corresponding ideals in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ are consequently:

- $(1+\sqrt{-3},1-\sqrt{-3})$,
- $(1+\sqrt{-3})$, $(1-\sqrt{-3})$ and $(2\sqrt{-3},4)$,
- $(2+2\sqrt{-3},4)$ and $(2)$,
- the "trivial" ideals $(4)$ and $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$.

Comment: I think （x＋1,x-1）is not maximal

Comment: @川村はるか What makes you think so? If you compute the quotient of $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)[X]/(X^2-1)$ by the ideal $(X+1, X-1) = (2,X-1)$ you get $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, which is a field.

Comment: Thank you, my careless mistake. I understand 8 ideals you listed is certainly ideals, but how did you find them? aren't there any other ideals? how to prove it? Thank you for my teacher, Claudius.

Comment: The ring in question has only 16 elements. So I computed all the ideals generated by some element. After that I computed all ideals generated by 2 elements and then observed that I could stop after that. This was a bit tedious, but at least it gives very explicit information. I am not sure how to do this, when the ring is very large.

Comment: I see ideals generated by 1 element is easy, But how did you notice ideals generated by 2 element is just （x＋１,x-1）? And Why are not there ideals which are generated by 3 elements?

Comment: If you look at the ideals generated by (at least) 2 elements (in this case there was only one), they are maximal. Either you compute the quotient (which is convenient), or you just add another element and show that you obtain the full ring. Maybe, you should do the work once. It is not difficult, but tedious.