# Ideal of $(\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z})[x]/(x^2-1)$

Tags: ring-theory

I want to find all ideal of $J=(\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z})[x]/(x^2-1)$.
The number of all elements of $J$ is just 16, so my text says it is easy to find all ideal by hand.

I can understand $J$ has just 16 elements, but I cannot go further,
I would be appreciated if you show me how to classify all ideal of $J$, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notation** 
Denote $z=ax+b\in J$ for $a,b\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, $J^+$ as the additional group on $J$, $[z_1,\dots,z_n]$ and $\langle z_1,\dots,z_n\rangle$ as the subgroup of $J^+$ and the ideal of $J$ generated by $z_1,\dots,z_n\in J$ respectively.

First comes the conclusion, the $7$ ideals: $$\{0\},I_0=\langle 2x+2\rangle=[2x+2],I_1=\langle 2\rangle=[2],I_2=\langle x+1\rangle=[x+1],I_3=\langle x+3\rangle=[x+3],I_4=I_1\bigcup I_2\bigcup I_3,J$$are all ideals in $J$ that we are looking for.

To find it, we can start with ideals like $\langle z\rangle,z\in J$. We know $$\langle z\rangle=\{jz\mid j=ax+b\in J\}=[z,xz]$$and $x^2=1$ in $J$, so, for example, $\langle x+2\rangle=J$. This is because $(x+2)$ and $x(x+2)$ is linear indepedent entries of order $4$ in $J^+$ and then the group generated by them are a subgroup with $16$ entries in $J^+$, which is undoutedly $J^+$ or $J$ itself. In other words, $\langle x+2\rangle=[x+2,2x+1]=J$. $\langle z\rangle=J$ holds for $z=1,3,x,x+2,2x+1,2x+3,3x,3x+2$ according to the same reason above as well.

To use the same methods, it's not difficult to find the ideals generated by the others. Here is another example:$\langle x+3\rangle=[x+3,3x+1]=[x+3,3(x+3)]=[x+3]=\{0,x+3,2x+2,3x+1\}$.

Up to now, we've found, in fact, all the ideals in $J$ but $I_4$ mentioned above, which is generated by more than one element.

Since $\langle z_1,z_2\rangle$ is trivial if $\langle z_1\rangle=J$ or $\langle z_2\rangle=J$, we assume $z_1,z_2\in I_1\bigcup I_2\bigcup I_3$($I_0$ is included in any of them). Noticed that $(2x)+(x+1)+(x+3)=0$, so any two of these three generate $I_4$, and further any two of $I_i-I_0,i=1,2,3$ generate $I_4$(*why?*). Since $\forall z\in J,2x+2\in\langle z\rangle$, the case for $\langle z_1,z_2\rangle$ is ended and the proof is ended, too.

What's more, if there is any other new ideal, one must satisfies $I_4<I'=\langle z_1,\dots,z_n\rangle(n\ge 2)<J^+$ and then $8=\mid I_4\mid<\mid I'\mid<\mid J^+\mid =16$, which is impossible for a subgroup of $J^+$.

Comment: In your answer,〈２x〉　is missing.there are 8 ideals.

Comment: For $2x\cdot{} x=2x^2=2,\langle 2x\rangle=\langle 2\rangle$. It seems to be consistent with $I_1$^_^

Comment: Thank you your answer! But https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883028/find-all-ideals-of-ring-mathbbz-sqrt-3-containing-4/1883109?noredirect=1#comment7510833_1883109 According to this, there are 8 ideals.

Comment: Okay, I've looked through and considered that question. The method I used here is still useful there. Since $2\sqrt{-3}\cdot \sqrt{-3}=-6$, $(2\sqrt{-3},4)=(2)$. I think it's a small mistake.

Comment: where did you mistake? Is the answer 8 ideals? or 7 ?which is true?sorry

Comment: Err…I mean 7, because his ideal table has two repeated ideals, $(2\sqrt{-3},4)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: Thank you ! I may ask more details, this is a quick note to thank you, teacher,Yao Fu.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea: Note that $J$ is isomorphic to

$$ R = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix} : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \right\} $$

via the correspondence $a+bx \leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$. From this, we observe:

- As an element of $R$ via the above correspondence, the determinant of $a+bx$ is $a^2-b^2$. So, $a+bx$ is a unit of $J$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ have different parities, i.e., $a+b$ is odd.
- The remaining 8 non-invertible elements may be partitioned into 5 different classes according to whether they only differ by multiplication by units:
  \begin{gather*}
   \{0\}, \quad
  A := \{ 2, 2x \}, \quad
  B := \{1+x, 3+3x\}, \\
  C := \{1+3x, 3+x\}, \quad
  D := \{2+2x\}.
  \end{gather*}

Now using the fact that

$$ A+B = B+C = C+A, \qquad AB = BC = CA = D, $$

we have total 7 different ideals:

- $\langle 0 \rangle$
- $\langle A \rangle = \langle A, D \rangle$
- $\langle B \rangle = \langle B, D \rangle$
- $\langle C \rangle = \langle C, D \rangle$
- $\langle D \rangle$
- $\langle A,B\rangle=\langle A,C\rangle = \langle B, C \rangle $
  $= \langle A, B, C \rangle=\langle A,B,D\rangle = \langle A,C,D\rangle = \langle B,C,D\rangle $
  $= \langle A, B, C, D \rangle$
- $J$